# How to move some videos out of my YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

I have had a personal YouTube channel with some personal videos (me playing guitar) for a while but recently I started to make business videos and uploading them to that same channel. There are about 30 videos total now so it would be hard to download and re-upload them. Plus, the videos would lose their ranking in YouTube.

Is there any option for me to move the personal videos out of the existing channels into a new one?

Comment: Unfortunately, YouTube doesn't support transferring videos from one account to another one - see [this](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2404846?hl=en) for the official word on that.

Comment: The above comment seems like the answer; would you be able to add it as one?

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot move videos between channels, you can download all your videos in the original quality (ie before the YouTube compression) via [Google Takeout](https://google.com/takeout) and then reupload them in bulk (though only 50 per day, after that, the upload rate gets slowed down to one more video every half an hour or so).